# Runge-Kutta methods for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, runge-kutta-methods

How are RK methods for solving time-dependent PDEs implemented?

I am trying to reproduce results of a thesis. It is a advection-diffusion unsteady equation. It is clearly mentioned that they have used RK method for time integration. I cannot use finite difference methods like Crank-Nicolson or any other method like that.

Thanks.

Comment: You should elaborate on your post. What is the context of your question? (why do you want to know?)

Comment: I have edited the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yeah, that's better.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional way of treating time-dependent PDE is to employ a method-of-lines like procedure [A], [B]. Although that approach was originally only referred to employing finite-difference for the spatial terms, the name persisted and is now used for methods that employ a particular method (Finite Difference/Element/Volume, Discontinuous Galerkin, ...) for the spatial derivatives and something different for the temporal terms.

In particular, for the advection diffusion equation

$$ \partial_t c = \nabla \cdot (D \nabla c) + a \cdot \nabla c + s$$
you would apply e.g. Finite Element for the spatial derivatives, i.e.,
$$\nabla \cdot (D \nabla c), \quad a \cdot \nabla c$$

which gives you then a semi-discretized system like

$$ \frac{d \boldsymbol C}{dt} = \boldsymbol F\big(\boldsymbol C(t) \big) $$

for which you can then use (in principle) any ODE solver, given an initial condition $\boldsymbol C(t_0) = \boldsymbol C_0$.

[A] [Application of the Method of Lines to Parabolic Partial
Differential Equations With Error Estimates](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/321574.321583)  
[B] [W. E. Schiesser. The numerical method of lines: integration of partial differential equations](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-numerical-method-of-lines/schiesser/978-0-12-624130-3)